Is there a way to lock the camera roll of a first person camera with raylib in c++?
I am trying to create a first-person game with gravity, collision, and all that other stuff with C++ and Raylib. I was working on the camera controls, and they are working very well, but I noticed that q and e rotate the camera. I do not want this functionality in my game. Is there a way to disable this?
Here is my code, btw:
 #include "raylib.h"

int main(void)
{
    int screenWidth = 1200;
    int screenHeight = 800;

    SetConfigFlags(FLAG_WINDOW_RESIZABLE | FLAG_VSYNC_HINT);
    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "Liminal");

    Camera camera = {0};
    camera.position = (Vector3){0.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f};
    camera.target = (Vector3){0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f};
    camera.up = (Vector3){0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f};
    camera.fovy = 45.0f;
    camera.projection = CAMERA_PERSPECTIVE;

    DisableCursor();

    SetTargetFPS(60);

    while (!WindowShouldClose())
    {
        UpdateCamera(&camera, CAMERA_FIRST_PERSON);

        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);

        BeginMode3D(camera);

        DrawPlane((Vector3){0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}, (Vector2){32.0f, 32.0f}, BLACK);

        DrawSphere(Vector3{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}, 1.0f, GREEN);

        EndMode3D();

        EndDrawing();
    }

    CloseWindow();

    return 0;
}


I don't know RayLib, but it seems the answer is yes write your own UpdateCamera function. See : How can i change camera3d movement speed in raylib. I think you can copy the source code mentioned and remove the lines that react to Q and E key presses

I tried to do that but it didn't work. I need to know what specific things need to change in order to remove this functionality, or at least a basic understanding of the things in rcamera.h
